# OnItemClick listener not working in Custom ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter, onitemclicklistener

I have created a custom list view and created my own adapter class
I have inflated the view with below code:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View streamrowView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.streamrow, parent,false);
    initUI(streamrowView);

    tvUserMsg.setText(values[position].Message);
    tvPostDate.setText(values[position].postDate);

    return streamrowView;
}



    private void initUI(View streamrowView) {
    tvUserMsg = (TextView) streamrowView.findViewById(R.id.tvUserMsg);
    tvPostDate = (TextView) streamrowView.findViewById(R.id.tvPostDate);

}
```

List view is working perfectly, but the set onItemClick listener event is not working

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> data, View v, int pos,
                long arg3) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext,  "list clicked" ,1).show();
            System.out.println("*****List clicked!!!");

        }
    });
```

is there any other approach for onItemClick listener for custom rows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            final View vi ;//= convertView;
            ViewHolder holder;
            // if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_mbc_language, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtViewLangItem = (TextView) vi
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtViewLangItem);

            holder.imgViewSelectedLang = (ImageView) vi
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgViewSelectedLang);

            vi.setTag(holder);

            vi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    BibleActivity.selectedLangCode = MBCLanguageListAdapter.this.resultsLang[position].languageCode;
                    MainActivity.SavePreferences("langCode",
                            BibleActivity.selectedLangCode,
                            MBCLanguageListAdapter.this.activity);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });

            holder.txtViewLangItem.setText(this.resultsLang[position].language);
            if (this.resultsLang[position].languageCode
                    .equals(BibleActivity.selectedLangCode)) {
                holder.imgViewSelectedLang.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            return vi;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {}
}
```

Comment: Code only-answers aren't really helpful. And your indentation is terrible.